# Pixel keeps removing Smart Lock devices

Tags: bluetooth, smart-lock

**Phone** Google Pixel
**OS** Android 9

I connect my phone to my car using Bluetooth, and to use it hands free it must be unlocked. I use Smart Lock to achieve this, by adding my car as a Bluetooth device to Smart Lock.

However, sometimes the device is removed from the list, and I can't figure out why.

Why is Android removing my Smart Lock devices?